# summation formula for $sin^2(2Nx)$ in terms of $sin^2(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

If we define, $\theta_m = \frac{\pi}{2^m}$ I found that I can compute $sin(x)$ for any $x \in \mathbb{R}$ to any desired precision using

$u_{n,m}=n \theta_m$ where $n,m \in \mathbb{N} \quad (1)$

$sin(\theta +n\theta)=sin(\theta)cos(n\theta)+cos(\theta)sin(n\theta) \quad (2)$

since I can show that:

$\forall \epsilon >0 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\exists n,m \in \mathbb{N}, |u_{n,m}-x|<\epsilon \quad (3)$

Now, I managed to show that:

$sin^2(2\theta)=2sin^2(\theta)-2sin^4(\theta)$

$sin^2(4\theta)=4sin^2(\theta)-12sin^4(\theta)+16sin^6(\theta)-8sin^8(\theta)$

And, I suspect that there's a general summation formula for $sin^2(2N \theta)$. Such a formula would allow me to approximate $sin(x)$ to any desired precision without using (2). However, I haven't managed to find it.

**Note:** The challenge is to derive such a summation formula using (2) and without assuming knowledge of Taylor's series or calculus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v=\sin^2(2Nx)$ and $u=\sin^2(x)$, then $1-2v = \cos(4Nx) = T_{2N}(\cos(2x)) = T_{2N}(1-2u)$,
hence
$$ v = \frac{1-T_{2N}(1-2u)}{2},\qquad \sin^2(2Nx)=\frac{1-T_{2N}(1-2\sin^2 x)}{2} $$
where $T_{2N}$ is a [Chebyshev polynomial of the first kind](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ChebyshevPolynomialoftheFirstKind.html).
Through De Moivre's formula we also have:
$$ T_{2N}(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{N}\binom{2N}{2k}(z^2-1)^k z^{2N-2k}$$
and
$$ \sin^2(2N x)   =  \sin^2(x)\cdot U_{2N-1}^2(\sin x).$$

Comment: That's nice. But, is there an elementary derivation? Chebyshev polynomials appear to require contour integrals in order to be defined.

Comment: @AidanRocke: they can be simply defined through $T_0(z)=1, T_1(z)=z$ and $$T_{n+2}(z)=2z T_{n+1}(z)-T_n(z), $$ i.e. through the cosine addition formulas.